# Regular express to validate url with ip and domain?

Tags: regex, url, ip-address

i am using following regular expression to validate a url that could be:

```
@"http[s]?://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ./?%&=]*)?";
```

**A domin**
www.abc.com  (Validates it)
subdomain.abc.com  (Validates it)

**An Ip Address**
192.168.0.1  (Validates it)
182.494.29.23  (Validates it)

I want to restrict non valid ip addresses
192.192   (Above Expression Validates it as well)
192.192.192 (Above Expression Validates it as well)

any one guide me what changes i need to add in above expression to restrict these non valid ip addresses?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to look at a page I wrote on the subject: [Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this regex:

```
/^http(s?)://((\w+\.)?\w+\.\w+|((2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}))(/)?$/gm
```

It's a bit lengthy but it works both with abc.domain.com, domain.com and valid IP addresses.
You can test it [here](http://regexr.com?329bj).

It's split into a "text" part, `(\w+\.)?\w+\.\w+` that matches any text without spaces and with one or two dots in it, and a numeric part, `((2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})` allowing four numbers between 0 and 255 separated by dots.

Optionally, there can be a slash at the end.

If you don't mean to allow domains composed by single characters (eg. a.b.c) but, say, at least like www.bit.ly (that is, with free prefix of 1 or more characters, "body" of three or more, and suffix of two or more), you can change the text part into:

```
(\w+\.)?\w{3,}\.\w{2,}
```

Reference:

http://RegExr.com?2ri07 (regex matching ip)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex. It supports http, https, ip address, ip address with different port and any domain name.

> /^http(s?)://((\w+.)?\w+.\w+|((2[0-5]{2}|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2}).){3}(2[0-5]{3}|1[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,2})(:\d{1,5})?)(((/)(.+)?)?)$/gm,